# Chronic InnoDB table corruption

Tags: mysql, innodb, corruption, percona

I have a high-use table (many updates/second) that every week or so appears to become corrupt. The logs are inconclusive however standard InnoDB recovery of the table (select into new table, truncate old table & insert back to old table) fixed our issue.

My first suggestion was to move the table from InnoDB to MEMORY due to it's high update throughput but that was denied. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to stop the apparent corruption?

MySQL Version: Percona XtraDB Cluster 5.5.24

OS: CentOS 6.2 64bit

**Edit:** The error shown in the logs is "Got error -1 when reading table"

Comment: Have you excluded hardware problems ? (bad sectors on disk).

Comment: Yea, the server is in our esxi cluster and there's no disk errors on the local storage or the SAN.